# Need help fixing system problems after downloading Lollipop 5.0 upgrade for Note 3 today

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-note-3

My device is a Galaxy Note 3. I was prompted to download a new system upgrade late last night (Lollipop 5.0). I clicked proceed and went to bed. I woke to find two recurring system errors, first being "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped", and "Unfortunately, Package Access Helper has stopped".

The phone will allow for sending and receiving of text messages and emails, I can also call out. No notifications show up on my phone even though I hear them come in; the Phone rings when someone calls but I cannot see who it is or answer it; Background screen is black; none of the phones buttons work either (aside from the power button). Research shows people with similar issues have cleared app caches (didnt work), or done a factory reset (would prefer not to). Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found some people who suggested wiping cache data instead of factory reset.  Did that just now and it's working great, with no loss of data!

- Power off.
- Power on in recovery mode (this is for the Note 3) by holding down the power, home and volume up buttons until the screen flickers.   I got red messagesaying Booting to Recovery partition or something like that... you get a list of items.
- Select Wipe Cache Partition using the volume buttons to move up or down. Power button to select.   It took maybe 5 seceonds to wipe the cache.
- Select Reboot.

And my phone is back!

Comment: I second this advice (+1)! You can always factory-reset later in case that didn't work :)